# Validation in Laravel on relationship

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I have a `persons` model that has a many-to-many relationship with its `group`. The person's name needs to be unique in its group but not on the persons table. How would ensure that?

My validation is done in the controller store method using `$request->validate(['name => ...`

I currently save the new person in a controller using simply - `Person::create([...`

Answer (score 0):

My simple approach is using a composite primary keys on pivot table and use basic exception handling like `try catch` stuff whenever inserting data is fail due to migration

```php
$table->foreignId('group_id') // Add any modifier to this column
$table->foreignId('person_id')  // Add any modifier to this column
$table->primary(['group_id', 'person_id']);
```

If you want to do it on controller, make sure to setup relationship. Then just use [Rule::notIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-not-in) Validation

```php
'name' => [
   'required',
   Rule::notIn(/* put your logic here */),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'exist' rule in Laravel Validation like that:
`'name' => 'exists:group,name,person_id,'.$id`
For more info you can check here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique